# Prove that a derivative with respect to a covariant 4-vector is a contravariant vector operator

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, differentiation, covariance

In special relativity, I know you can prove that the derivative with respect to a contravariant 4-vector component transforms like a covariant vector operator by using the chain rule, but I can't work out how to prove the inverse, that the derivative with respect to a covariant 4-vector component transforms like a contravariant vector operator.

Comment: Does not the chain rule work in the same pattern?

Comment: I don't think so. But if you can show me how it does, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

$$\partial'^{\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x'_{\mu}}=\frac{\partial x'^{\lambda}}{\partial x'_{\mu}} \frac{\partial x^{\sigma}}{\partial x'^{\lambda}} \frac{\partial x_{\nu}}{\partial x^{\sigma}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\nu}} = g^{\mu \lambda}\Lambda_{\lambda}^{\sigma}g_{\sigma \nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\nu}}=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu}\partial^{\nu}$$
So contravariant.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have the inverse transformations for 4-vector components:

$$
\tag 1 \mathbf r = \mathbf r' + \Gamma \mathbf u \frac{(\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf r' )}{c^{2}} + \gamma \mathbf u t{'} , \quad t = \gamma \left(t' + \frac{(\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf r' )}{c^{2}}\right).
$$

Here $\Gamma = \frac{(\gamma - 1)}{\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}$.

Then by using chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t' } = \frac{\partial t}{\partial t'}\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + \frac{\partial x_{j}}{\partial t{'}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}}, \quad \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i}'} = \frac{\partial t}{\partial x_{i}'}\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + \frac{\partial x_{j}}{\partial x_{i}'}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}}
$$

you may get by using $(1)$

$$ 
\frac{\partial t}{\partial t'} = \gamma, \quad \frac{\partial x_{j}}{\partial t{'}} = \gamma u_{j}, \quad \frac{\partial t}{\partial x_{i}'} = \frac{\gamma u_{i}}{c^{2}},
$$

$$\frac{\partial x_{j}}{\partial x_{i}{'}} = \delta_{ij} + \Gamma \frac{u_{j}u_{i}}{c^{2}} \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
\nabla_{i}{'} = \frac{\gamma u_{i}}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + \sum_{j}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}}\delta_{ij} + \frac{\Gamma u_{i}u_{j}}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}}\right) = \frac{\gamma u_{i}}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i}} + \frac{\Gamma}{c^{2}}u_{i}(\mathbf u \nabla).
$$

From these equations you may get

$$\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t'} = \frac{1}{c}\gamma\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + \frac{1}{c}\gamma \sum_{j}u_{j}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{j}} = \gamma \left( \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + \frac{1}{c}(\mathbf u \nabla )\right),
$$

$$ 
\nabla ' = \nabla + \Gamma\frac{\mathbf u}{c^{2}}(\mathbf u \nabla) + \frac{\gamma \mathbf u}{c^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}.
$$
So $\partial_{\alpha}$ operator transforms as contravariant vector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this the simplest way to prove it.?

Comment: @user2582713 : my answer in only the explicit form of the statement
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\mu}{'}} = \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\ \nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}},
$$
which shows that derivative transforms under Lorentz transformation as contravariant vector:
$$
\nabla {'}_{\beta} = \Lambda_{\beta}^{\ \alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}.
$$

Comment: I'm afraid I'm confused. Isn't that the derivative with respect to a contravariant component? And shouldn't there be a prime in the derivative after the first equal sign?

Comment: @user2582713 : starting from inverse transformations of covariant 4-vector I get direct contravariant transformation for 4-derivative. You meaned this one, didn't you?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use the Lorentz transformation. We're asked to prove a statement that's much more general than relativity. It's a fact about differential geometry.

Comment: @BenCrowell Could you provide such a general proof?

Comment: @user2582713 : I have provided general proof (for linear transformations) in my first comment. I have read you question inattentively so I have decided that it's about special relativity.

Comment: @AndrewMcAddams I am studying special relativity. What I'm confused about is that to prove that the derivative with respect to a contravariant component is covariant requires a single line using the chain rule whereas to prove the inverse takes however many lines your answer took. I wanted to know if there was an answer to my question as simple as the using the chain rule.